# How to cast varbinary to varchar in presto

Tags: presto

I have the following query where shopname is stored as varbinary instead of varchar type.

```
select shopname, itemname
from shop_profile
where cast(shopname as varchar) = 'Starbucks';
```

This query returns an error "line 4:7: Cannot cast varbinary to varchar"

May I know if anyone knows what is the correct syntax to convert varbinary to varchar?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [from_utf8](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#from_utf8) function.

Also, [to_utf8](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#to_utf8) can cast the literal 'Starbucks' to varbinary type.